# Transaction Rejected, bitcoins not returned to wallet?

Tags: electrum, unconfirmed-transactions

My transaction is still coming up unconfirmed on my electrum (ver 2.6.4) wallet after 2 days. When I open it on blockchain I get the following message:

"Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction was previously accepted but has been pruned from our database."

Have I lost my bitcoins or what can I do to recover them?

Transaction can be viewed here:

https://blockchain.info/tx/ec7e3a90d4434e29044a735f12239796d0eb51ad231417dfa61876a3cfc8cc3f

Answer (score 0):

> Have I lost my bitcoins

no. unless confirmed the bitcoins are still yours

> or what can I do to recover them?

**you** can do nothing. you should wait and spend your time for learning

Comment: wait for what? my wallet is still showing them as unconfirmed?